# How to set the value of a $CustomParameter$ in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, project-template

I´m developing a project template and i need a custom parameter, but i dont know how to set it a value in my code instead vstemplate file:

```
<CustomParameter Name="$CustomParameter$" Value=""/>  
<CustomParameter Name="$CustomParameter$" Value=""/>
```

In this method with the Dictionary i can set a value to $CustomParameter$ but when my code is generated the $CustomParameter$ still there.

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject,
        Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
        WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {
        replacementsDictionary.Add("$CustomParameter$", name);
    }
```